# How to find global Maximum of this function.

Tags: real-analysis, maxima-minima

This question which I am asking is to be used in another question and I am unable to do this. So, I am asking for help.

> Consider the function$s_n(x)=\frac{2}{\pi} \int_{0}^{x} \frac{\sin (2nt)} {\sin (t)} dt $ . I proved that this function has Local Maxima at $x_1 ,x_3,x_5,...,x_{2n-1}$ where $x_m=\frac{m \pi } {2n}$.

But I am not able to prove that $s_n(\frac{\pi}{2n}) $is global maximium.

The method I thought was to compare all the local maximum but I am not able to compute the integral involving $s_n(x)$ .

I think that it has to be done in some other way( using some clever way and indirectly) and I am not able to figure out that .

So, Can you please help with that?

Comment: did you try to plot for different values of $n$? You'll see that the global maximum is attained at the first and nth local maximum.

Comment: @PierreCarre Do you mean using a software/ program? No, Also I want to do it theoretically without even help of calculater

Comment: Sure, but if know the final answer this may guide you in the theoretical proof...

Comment: @PierreCarre Ya it's given in the statement  of question itself $\pi /2n $ is the answer

Comment: Taking a better look, my first comment is not correct. The global maximum is attained only at the first local maximum.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Above Figure illustrates the graph of $f(t):=\frac{\sin(2nt)}{\sin(t)}$ on $[0, \pi]$.

**Idea.**
The idea to achieve the goal is very simple
thank to the following geometric observations:

- **Obs1.** $f_n$ is symmetric with center $x=\pi/2$.
- **Obs2.** Obs1 implies that $s_n$ is symmetric with axis $x=\pi/2$. Thus, it is sufficient to prove that $s_n( \frac{\pi}{2n} )$ is the maximum of $s_n$ on $[0, \frac{\pi}{2}]$, i.e. prove that it is the maximum of the set $\{ s_n( \frac{i\pi}{2n}) : i=1, ... n\}$.
- **Obs3.** The area of $f_n$ over $[\frac{i\pi}{2n}, \frac{(i+1)\pi}{2n}]$, denoted by $s_n^i$, is decreasing for $i=0, ..., n-1$.
- **Obs4.**
  \begin{align}
  s_n( \frac{\pi}{2n} )  & = s_n^1\\
  s_n( \frac{2\pi}{2n} ) & = s_n^1-s_n^2\leq s_n^1\\
  s_n( \frac{3\pi}{2n} ) & = s_n^1-(s_n^2-s_n^3) \leq s_n^1\\
  s_n( \frac{4\pi}{2n} ) & = s_n^1-(s_n^2-s_n^3) -s_n^4 \leq s_n^1\\
  .....
  \end{align}

Hence we conclude that $s_n^1$ is the global maximum and $\frac{\pi}{2n}$ is global maxima on $[0,\pi]$.

Based on geometric properties of $f_n$, similar arguments can be applied to prove that $\frac{\pi}{2n}$ is global maxima on $[0,2\pi]$. Since$f_n$ is periodic $2\pi$, thus $\frac{\pi}{2n}$ is global maxima on $\mathbb R$.

---

We now move into the details.

**Proof of Obs1.** We need to show $f_n(x)=-f_n(\pi-x)$. Indeed,
\begin{align}
f_n(\pi-t)     & = \frac{\sin(2n(\pi-t))}{\sin(\pi-t)}\\
           & = -\frac{\sin(2nt)}{\sin(t)}\\
           & = -f_n(t).
\end{align}

**Proof of Obs2.**
We need to show $s_n(x)=s_n(\pi-x)$.
Indeed,
\begin{align}
s_n(x)     & = \int_0^{x}  f_n(t) dt\\
           & = \int_0^{x} -f_n(\pi-t) dt\\
           & = \int_{\pi-x}^\pi -f_n(t) dt\\
           & = \int_0^{\pi-x} f_n(t) dt\\
           & = s_n(\pi-x).
\end{align}
Here the fourth equation follows from the fact that $\int_0^\pi f_n(t)dt=0$ as $f_n$ is symmetric with center $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$.

**Proof of Obs3.**
Let $x_i=\frac{i\pi}{2n}$ for $i=1, n$.
\begin{align}
s^i_n      & = \int_{x_i} ^{x_{i+1}} |f_n(t)| dt\\
           & = \int_{x_i} ^{x_{i+1}}  \frac{|\sin(2nt)|}{\sin(t)} dt\\
           & = \int_{x_i+x_1} ^{x_{i+1}+x_1}  \frac{|\sin(2n(t+x_1))|}{\sin(t+x_1)} dt\\
           & = \int_{x_{i+1}} ^{x_{i+2}}  \frac{|\sin(2nt)|}{\sin(t+x_1)} dt\\
           & < \int_{x_{i+1}} ^{x_{i+2}}  \frac{|\sin(2nt)|}{\sin(t)} dt\\
           & = s^{i+1}_n
\end{align}
Here we have used $\sin(t+x_1)>\sin(t)$ on $[0, \frac{\pi}{2}]$.

**Proof of Obs4.** This is easy because we just need to investigate the sign of $f_n$. Note that we are working on $[0, \frac{\pi}{2}]$ and $\sin(t)$ is positive now.